# Android Studio Github Wierd Commiting

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio, commit

Well, I have an interesting problem!
Today I have set up my Android Studio project with GitHub. All went well and I made a commit and pushed it up into GitHub. But then I looked at the commit author and it said: KodekPL authored 2 minutes ago! Wait, wait, that is not me! My username is Nicba1010! Everything works, except the fact that supposedly I am not the commiter!
Repo [LINK](https://github.com/Nicba1010/eRasporedApp)

Comment: Does the email on your local git settings match the/an email configured for your github account?

Comment: Yes it does!    (filler)

Answer (score 1):

I bet you play Minecraft. And you run your own server. Spigot perhaps? ;)

Upon further investigation, KodekPL's GitHub email address is "unconfigured@null.spigotmc.org". You probably have a Spigot MC server on your computer, and git picked that up as your email address, hence the wrong author on GitHub. :) Again, setting the global variables fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the global user and email variables fixed the problem!